# SMTP error 5.5.1

Tags: c#, email, smtp

following is my code to send confirmation mail using smtp server i C#!! but getting error 5.5.1 client authentication always!!! please help!!

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();

try
{
    m.From = new MailAddress("swamycns95@gmail.com");
    m.To.Add(email);
    m.Subject = "This is a Test Mail";
    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    m.Body = "test gmail";
    sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    sc.Port = 587;
    sc.EnableSsl = true;
    System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("swamycns95@gmail.com", "cnstvm36");
    sc.Credentials = basicCredential;
    sc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    sc.Send(m);
    Response.Write("Email Send successfully");
}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMessage(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: You should say which programming language that is...

Comment: Programming language is c#

Answer (score 0):

By setting `sc.UseDefaultCredentials` to `true`, you are telling it to ignore the credentials you gave it and instead load the credentials from `app.config`.

The solution is to set `UseDefaultCredentials` to `false`.

Note: You may need to set `UseDefaultCredentials` to `false` *before* setting the `Credentials` property. I can't remember the order you have to set these properties, but I think it matters.

Comment: I have changed the credentials as you have told. I'm a beginner in C# and ASP.Net, so please tel me how to use "app.config" file. I didn't understood the concept of app.config !!!

P.S. The error still exists.

Comment: You don't want to use app.config, you want to use the credentials you are creating in the app, don't you? So why are you asking me how to use app.config? I'm only telling you that's not working *because* it's using the app.config credentials because you set `UseDefaultCredentials = true`

Comment: I changed UseDefaultCredentials to false and worked out every possibility of the order of properties !! Still error exists!!!

Comment: Are you sure the credentials you are providing are correct?

Comment: yeah!! credentials are all correct..    Is there any specifications for system,, i.e. I'm using a laptop. Does that matter !!